# chrome extension changing host/domain warning

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will notify me of host/domain changes when I'm testing a specific website. Often links will be present that point towards developer or live environments and I'd like to be warned if I follow one of these links as the websites are often identical.

Edit for clarity: I want it to alert me when a link takes me away from http(s)://example.staging.something.com and ends up on the live site http(s)://www.example.com or the dev site http(s)://example.dev.something.com

So far I have managed to create a script that identifies when I am on a staging url (our test environment) however I've been unable to reverse this logic to give me a warning when I navigate to a url that doesn't contain 'staging'.

My manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "A What URL",
"description": "This extension monitors and warns you of domain changes",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
},

"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"webNavigation"
]
}
```

my background.js

```
   chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(e) {
        alert ("you are still on staging!");
  }, {url: [{hostContains: 'staging'}]});
```

I'm sure this is simple but it appears my brain is far simpler!

Comment: At which point you want to be notified? And what do you want to do when it's caught?

Comment: I mean, I can answer your question as-is (how to invert logic in that sample), but maybe there's a better-suited answer depending on your "ideal" logic.

Comment: Once that transition has happened is fine for me, I think the onCommitted is the right action for that although I did look at the others available. Initially I only want to be warned, the alert popping up is enough however eventually I'd like to utilise the notifications api to make it a bit more flashy

Comment: I mean, your goal is not to prevent navigation, only be notified?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly!

Comment: 1) Please look at Rob's solution, it's different and worth considering, 2) please don't edit your solution into the question. Just add it as another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't "invert" the filter, so you'll have to catch all events and filter in the code.

Here come the Chrome Events. Your code suggests you treat them like DOM events (with the `e` parameter). Instead, they pass arguments depending on the event in question, sometimes several.

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted), you'll see that the expected callback format is:

```
function(object details) {...};
```

Where `details` will contain, among other things, a `url` property.

So you'll have:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
  // Regexp matches first "//", followed by any number of non-/, followed by "staging"
  if(!details.url.match(/[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*staging/)) {
    alert ("This is no longer staging!");
  }
});
```

Note that this is going to be extremely annoying unless you can turn it off - it will match almost any page, after all.

Comment: Many thanks for this I had tried messing around with If statements using e.url but hadn't used .match method. However this currently as you suggested alerts for every page including the ones I didn't want it to! the exact format of the url string which is safe is either http://*.staging.something.com/* and https://*.staging.something.com/*

Comment: Sorry if the above is not clear, I am getting the alert popping up when viewing our staging site which should be the only place I don't see the alert

Comment: That is strange. I tested my regexp and it seems fine.. Try to add `detail.url` to the alert.

Comment: Ahh ok so that has opened a whole new can of worms. It seems to trigger twice for about:blank and then moves on to 2 more instances related to php. I tried changing it to webNavigation.onCompleted thinking that would work but I get the same results.

Comment: You could try `tabs.onCreated` and `tabs.onUpdated` instead (you'll need the `"tabs"` permission to access the URL)

Comment: So I've essentially got it working with your regex solution but now using tabs and onUpdated however it's still producing the alert many times, between 2-3 when it detects the URL is missing 'staging'. If I enable it and load a new tab for example it produces 3 alerts on the chrome://newtab/ URL. If I then refresh the tab it produces the alert twice and any other refresh on the same page produces two. Any ideas how I can suppress the additional alert messages? Many thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: `onUpdated` fires multiple times. Try to filter by status `comlpete`.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it! `if(!url.match(/[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*staging/) && changeInfo.status=="complete"){
    alert ("WTF!!! " +url);` Seems to only trigger once now!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem.

- Use the [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) (or [`.onSendHeaders`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onSendHeaders)) event to get notified when a request is sent to your production website, and check whether the `Referer` header is set to your staging site. This only works if the document referrer is set (this won't be the case if you're navigating from https to http, or if the "noreferrer" [referrer policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) is set).
- In the absence of a referer, use the [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and/or [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) APIs to track the navigation state of a page, and do whatever you want when you detect that the transition production -> dev occurs. Implementing this correctly is very difficult.

Here is a sample for the first method:

```js
// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    var referer;
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
        var header = details.requestHeaders[i];
        if (header.name.toLowerCase() === 'referer' && header.value) {
            referer = header.value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (referer && /^https?:\/\/dev\.example\.com(\/|$)/.test(referer)) {
        alert('Navigated from dev to production!');
    }
}, {
    urls: ['*://production.example.com/*', '*://prod.example.com/*'],
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'] // Track navigations, not img/css/etc.
}, ['requestHeaders']);
```

Example of manifest.json to test the previous logic:

```js
{
    "name": "Detect nav from dev to prod",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is definitely a better solution, though I asked OP carefully as to his requirements. This solution is above and beyond :)

Comment: @Xan The OP started a conversation over email with me before posting this question, so that makes mind-reading a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my final solution as an answer as requested in case anyone else is interested in the future.

Many thanks to both Xan and Rob with the help! If I could tick both I would but in the end I ended up ticking the one that led to my implementation.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
    };

   chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
       var tab = tabs[0];
       var url = tab.url;

       if(!url.match(/[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*staging/) &&   changeInfo.status=="complete"){
           alert ("WTF!!! " +url); 
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to query the current tab if some other tab finishes loading?

Comment: As stated before I'm sure this isn't the cleanest implementation and I could have gotten access to all the data inside the changeInfo however when I tried to implement it using that I kept getting an error so I just reverted to using something that worked.

Comment: My point being, if you open some tab in the background by middle-clicking, or some other page refreshes, your code will look at the currently visible tab - is that correct behavior?

Comment: I'm not expecting to open any additional tabs or change the focus to another tab during page load if that's what you mean?